# MongoDB - How to optimize this find/update

Tags: python, mongodb, asynchronous, pymongo

I am brand new to MongoDB and Python and have to write a script using pymongo. There is a website where users can perform searches, and on the backend there is MongoDB with one collection which stores all users' search history, and one collection which stores all users.

I need to iterate over all users, get all their search history for the past 30 days and take the sum, and then set that sum in one of their user fields. Below is what I wrote. Is there a way to speed this up, i.e. by using aggregation instead, or by multithreading it, or making it async?

```
import pymongo
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from bson.objectid import ObjectId


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    mongohost = '10.0.0.1'
    mongoport = 27017

    mongoclient = pymongo.MongoClient(mongohost, mongoport)
    mongodb = mongoclient["maindb"]
    mongo_search_logs_collection = mongodb["searchlogs"]
    mongo_users_collection = mongodb["users"]

    days_to_subtract_from_today = 30
    search_count_start_date = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days_to_subtract_from_today)).date()

    count = 0

    # Iterate over all users and update searchCount value
    for x in mongo_users_collection.find():

        # Get total searches last X days
        total_search_count = mongo_search_logs_collection.count_documents({
            'createdBy': ObjectId(x['_id']),
            'created': {'$gte': datetime(search_count_start_date.year, search_count_start_date.month, search_count_start_date.day)}
        })

        # Update searchCount value
        mongo_users_collection.update_one({
            '_id': ObjectId(x['_id'])
        }, {
            '$set': {
                'searchCount': total_search_count
            }
        }, upsert=False)

        # Increment counter
        count += 1

    print("Processed " + str(count) + " records")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a way of doing the job using `aggregation` and `bulk` operation:

```py
import pymongo
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from bson.objectid import ObjectId


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    mongohost = '10.0.0.1'
    mongoport = 27017

    mongoclient = pymongo.MongoClient(mongohost, mongoport)
    mongodb = mongoclient["maindb"]
    mongo_search_logs_collection = mongodb["searchlogs"]
    mongo_users_collection = mongodb["users"]

    days_to_subtract_from_today = 30
    search_count_start_date = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days_to_subtract_from_today)).date()

    cursor = mongo_search_logs_collection.aggregate([
        {
            "$match":{
                "created": {"$gte": datetime(search_count_start_date.year, search_count_start_date.month, search_count_start_date.day)}
            }
        },
        {
            "$group":{
                "_id": "$createdBy", "searchCount": { "$sum": 1 }
            }
        }
    ])

    bulk = mongo_users_collection.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
    for res in cursor:
        bulk.find({ "_id": res["_id"] }).update({ "$set": { "searchCount": res["searchCount"] } }, upsert=False)

    bulk.execute()
```

Let me know if you have any problem or a question since I didn't test it ;)

Answer (score 1):

As you are querying the **mongo_search_logs_collection** multiple times in the loop, that will slow down the processing. Instead you can get the searchCount of users in single shot and then update them. This will be quite faster. Check below stmt for fetching count for all the users in single shot.

```
mongo_search_logs_collection.aggregate(
    [
      {
        "$match": {
          "created": {
            "$gte": datetime(search_count_start_date.year, search_count_start_date.month, search_count_start_date.day)
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": "$createdBy",
          "total_search_count": {
            "$sum": 1
          }
        }
      }
    ]
)
```